# Rewrite multiple right joins to left joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, relational-algebra, right-join

I read that

```
SELECT * FROM table_0 
    RIGHT JOIN table_1 ON table_0.col_0 = table_1.col_0;
```

is the same as:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
    LEFT JOIN table_0 ON table_0.col_0 = table_1.col_0;
```

How do I rewrite a longer query, let's say:

```
SELECT * FROM  table_0
    RIGHT JOIN table_1 ON table_1.col_0 = table_0.col_0
    RIGHT JOIN table_2 ON table_2.col_1 = table_1.col_1
    RIGHT JOIN table_3 ON table_3.col_2 = table_2.col_2;
```

to use only LEFT JOINS? I would be interested in a generic solution to such problem.

I'm specifically interested in PostgreSQL dialect if it does matter.
From the explain output I can see that simply replacing LEFT to RIGHT is not enough here. The queries return different number of rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reverse the tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_3 LEFT JOIN
     table_2
     ON table_3.col_2 = table_2.col_2 LEFT JOIN
     table_1
     ON table_2.col_1 = table_1.col_1 LEFT JOIN
     table_0 
     ON table_1.col_0 = table_0.col_0;
```

A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all tables in the *first* table, regardless of whether the condition evaluates to true, false, or NULL.  A `RIGHT JOIN` keeps all rows in the second table, regardless of the condition.

I want to note that this is true for the `ON` conditions as you have written them.  It might not be true for all `ON` conditions.